# How to delete locked directories in a NANT Build Script

Tags: regex, nant

My build script intermittently crashes when attempting to delete a folder that has a lock on it. I'm trying to add code that will attempt to remove the lock and delete the folder if successful. I'm using handle.exe to get the process that is locking the folder, then I'm feeding the output to the Nant Regex task. The regex task is unable to find a match for the process id.  Here is my code:

```
  <regex pattern="(?&lt;Name&gt;\w+\.\w+)\s+pid:\s+(?&lt;PID&gt;\b(\d+)\b)\s+type:\s+(?&lt;Type&gt;\w+)\s+\w+:\s+(?&lt;Path&gt;.*)" 
         input="foo.txt"
         options="Singleline"
         failonerror="false"/>
```

According to the NANT docs, it mentions to use the `&lt;` and `&gt;` in place of angle brackets.

When I test the pattern in a regex tester, with the output from handle.exe it works.

Any thoughts?

EDIT: Here is some sample output that the above pattern should match. The path wraps to the next line here in the editor.

explorer.exe       pid: 3236   type: File          11E8: C:\InstallOutput\AHLTA\Client\Config1\Current\DiskImages\DISK1
explorer.exe       pid: 3236   type: File          1670: C:\InstallOutput\AHLTA\Client\Config1\Current\DiskImages\DISK1

Comment: Did you try removing the `\b` word boundaries around the PID? They shouldn't be necessary, since you already match whitespace on both sides of it. Can you give some sample strings that it should match?

Comment: @BrianStephens Thank you for the suggestion. I tried removing the \b around the PID but that didn't help. Didn't appear to change anything.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work by adding the following task prior to the regex task.

```
<loadfile file="foo.txt" property="handle.output.text"/>
```